# Error in the Random Forest model fit with GridSearch while using a pipeline()

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am trying to implement ColumnTransformer() and Pipeline() following this document:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html

I  have encountered a ValueError using the prediction pipeline in a grid search.

My data is of mixed types with a binomial target (the 'left' column has values 'yes' or 'no').

department       category
promoted            int64
review            float64
projects            int64
salary             object
tenure            float64
satisfaction      float64
bonus               int64
avg_hrs_month     float64
left               object
dtype: object

here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

    department  promoted    review  projects    salary  ...     left
0   operations  0           0.577569    3       low             no
1   operations  0           0.751900    3       medium          no
2   support     0           0.722548    3       medium          yes
3   logistics   0           0.675158    4       high            no
4   sales       0           0.676203    3       high            no


ord_features = ["salary","left"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()

cat_features = ["department"]
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", ordinal_transformer, selector(dtype_include="object")),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include="category")),
    ]
)

clf = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())]
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_over, y_over, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, random_state=32)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

Out:
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', OrdinalEncoder(),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9C38CA0>),
                                                 ('cat',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9D863A0>)])),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])



param_grid = {
  'max_depth':[30, 40, 50], 
  'n_estimators':[ 80, 100, 120, 130, 150]
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid,scoring='roc_auc', cv=6)

Out:
GridSearchCV(cv=6,
             estimator=Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                                        ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num',
                                                                         OrdinalEncoder(),
                                                                         <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9C38CA0>),
                                                                        ('cat',
                                                                         OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                                                         <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9D863A0>)])),
                                       ('classifier',
                                        RandomForestClassifier())]),
             param_grid={'max_depth': [30, 40, 50],
                         'n_estimators': [80, 100, 120, 130, 150]},
             scoring='roc_auc')


grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
Out:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_36048/20025057.py in <module>
----> 1 grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    889                 return results
    890 
--> 891             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    892 
    893             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1390     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1391         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1392         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1393 
   1394 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    836                     )
    837 
--> 838                 out = parallel(
    839                     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    840                         clone(base_estimator),

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1046             # remaining jobs.
   1047             self._iterating = False
-> 1048             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1049                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1050 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    864                 return False
    865             else:
--> 866                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    867                 return True
    868 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    782         with self._lock:
    783             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 784             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    785             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    786             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    209     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    210         with config_context(**self.config):
--> 211             return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    212 
    213 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, split_progress, candidate_progress, error_score)
    667             cloned_parameters[k] = clone(v, safe=False)
    668 
--> 669         estimator = estimator.set_params(**cloned_parameters)
    670 
    671     start_time = time.time()

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in set_params(self, **kwargs)
    186             Pipeline class instance.
    187         """
--> 188         self._set_params("steps", **kwargs)
    189         return self
    190 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in _set_params(self, attr, **params)
     52                 self._replace_estimator(attr, name, params.pop(name))
     53         # 3. Step parameters and other initialisation arguments
---> 54         super().set_params(**params)
     55         return self
     56 

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in set_params(self, **params)
    238             key, delim, sub_key = key.partition("__")
    239             if key not in valid_params:
--> 240                 raise ValueError(
    241                     "Invalid parameter %s for estimator %s. "
    242                     "Check the list of available parameters "

ValueError: Invalid parameter max_depth for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', OrdinalEncoder(),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9E1CE80>),
                                                 ('cat',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000028FD9EFEEB0>)])),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

So it gives me an error after grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train), ValueError: Invalid parameter max_depth for estimator Pipeline.

I have printed out the estimator's list of parameters:

```
clf.get_params().keys()
dict_keys(['memory', 'steps', 'verbose', 'preprocessor', 'classifier', 'preprocessor__n_jobs', 'preprocessor__remainder', 'preprocessor__sparse_threshold', 'preprocessor__transformer_weights', 'preprocessor__transformers', 'preprocessor__verbose', 'preprocessor__verbose_feature_names_out', 'preprocessor__num', 'preprocessor__cat', 'preprocessor__num__categories', 'preprocessor__num__dtype', 'preprocessor__num__handle_unknown', 'preprocessor__num__unknown_value', 'preprocessor__cat__categories', 'preprocessor__cat__drop', 'preprocessor__cat__dtype', 'preprocessor__cat__handle_unknown', 'preprocessor__cat__sparse', 'classifier__bootstrap', 'classifier__ccp_alpha', 'classifier__class_weight', 'classifier__criterion', 'classifier__max_depth', 'classifier__max_features', 'classifier__max_leaf_nodes', 'classifier__max_samples', 'classifier__min_impurity_decrease', 'classifier__min_samples_leaf', 'classifier__min_samples_split', 'classifier__min_weight_fraction_leaf', 'classifier__n_estimators', 'classifier__n_jobs', 'classifier__oob_score', 'classifier__random_state', 'classifier__verbose', 'classifier__warm_start'])
```

If do a gridsearch without a pipeline, I can get best estimators as follows:
n_estimators = 150, max_depth=30.

What can be wrong with my pipeline?

Comment: The parameters in `param_grid` should be specified as `'classifier__max_depth'` and `'classifier__n_estimators'` (from the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html): [...] <<The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be cross-validated together while setting different parameters. *For this, it enables setting parameters of the various steps using their names and the parameter name separated by a '__'*. >>

Comment: well spotted, this was indeed the case!

Comment: do you also know why when I use f1_score(
  y_test, 
  clf.predict(X_test)
)   I am getting a ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label. It should be one of ['no', 'yes']. Do I need to add f1_score in the pipeline?

Comment: Imo the point is that on one side you correctly fitted your `clf` classifier on your train data. On the other side, you didn't transform test data accordingly (therefore your `left` column eg is still in an unprocessed form --> it has unique values ['no', 'yes']). By transforming your test data via `clf.transform(X_test, y_test)` you'd be able to apply the same processing to test data. At that point you'd possibly have column `left` ordinally encoded and you'd be able to call `.f1_score()` without specifying `pos_label`.

Comment: As last remark, be aware that by calling `OrdinalEncoder` without specifying parameter `categories` manually, you might incur in the possibility that value 'yes' (positive class) is associated to 0 and 'no' to 1 - which might then generate confusion when reading results from the scorer (provided that I can't know the reason for which you're using `OrdinalEncoder` on your target). Indeed, `pos_label` in `f1_score` should be the integer or string representing the positive class in your binary classification pb.

Comment: what encoder would you use for the target? I thought LabelEncoder() and OrdinalEncoder() give the same output, no?   thank you very much for your help today.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree with you - my sentence was a bit unfortunate - but I would rather apply `LabelEncoder` on the target, though perhaps in your case also using `OrdinalEncoder` shouldn't cause any problem. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder#:~:text=Piotr%27s%20right%20about%20the%20general%20definitions%2Fusages%3A%20Ordinal%20encoding,variables%20%28where%20order%20doesn%27t%20matter%2C%20like%20blonde%2C%20brunette%29 gives a nice overview.

Comment: i have used label_features = ["left"]
label_transformer = LabelEncoder() and ord_features = ["salary"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder(), and now getting ValueError: A given column ('left') is not a column of the dataframe :/ does it mean I should not encode the target column via the pipeline?

Comment: I'd add (and that's another thing I should have implied) that imo (but I might be wrong) there's no much necessity to *LabelEncode* the target variable being a simple binary without need for an order - for instance. You can just replace it ex-ante with `df['left'].replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0}, inplace=True)` eg. For your issue, I might guess it is now related to the usage in `ColumnTransformer`, but I would say that for further details it might be better to post your updated piece of code.